# How default time with interval from another column TIMESTAMP sql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

There are 2 columns, how do I get the date from the first + 30 days to be written to Date_2 in SQL

```
CREATE TABLE DAS(
    Date_1 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Date_2 TIMESTAMP  DEFAULT
)
```

Comment: `UPDATE DAS SET Date_2=DATE_ADD(Date_1, INTERVVAL + 30 DAY);` ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The first 30 days of *what*?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+ expressions can be used as default values. So you can just use `timestampadd()` to add 30 minutes to the `current_timestamp`.

```
CREATE TABLE das
             (date_1 timestamp
                     NOT NULL
                     DEFAULT current_timestamp,
              date_2 timestamp
                     DEFAULT (timestampadd(minute,
                                           30,
                                           current_timestamp)));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d98a1c8400532e4c34ebfcaf8607e13d)